# How to concatenate pandas column with list values into one list?

Tags: python, list, pandas

I have a dataframe with one of its column having a list at each index. I want to concatenate these lists into one list. I am using

```
ids = df.loc[0:index, 'User IDs'].values.tolist()
```

However, this results in 
`['[1,2,3,4......]']` which is a string. Somehow each value in my list column is type `str`. I have tried converting using `list()`, `literal_eval()` but it does not work. The `list()` converts each element within a list into a string e.g. from `[12,13,14...]` to `['['1'',','2',','1',',','3'......]']`.

How to concatenate pandas column with list values into one list? Kindly help out, I am banging my head on it for several hours.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

consider the dataframe `df`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(col1=[[1, 2, 3]] * 2))
print(df)

        col1
0  [1, 2, 3]
1  [1, 2, 3]
```

## `pandas` simplest answer

```
df.col1.sum()

[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
```

## `numpy.concatenate`

```
np.concatenate(df.col1)

array([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3])
```

## `chain`

```
from itertools import chain

list(chain(*df.col1))

[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
```

---

***response to comments:***
I think your columns are strings

```
from ast import literal_eval

df.col1 = df.col1.apply(literal_eval)
```

If instead your column is string values that look like lists

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(col1=['[1, 2, 3]'] * 2))
print(df)  # will look the same

        col1
0  [1, 2, 3]
1  [1, 2, 3]
```

However `pd.Series.sum` does not work the same.

```
df.col1.sum()

'[1, 2, 3][1, 2, 3]'
```

We need to evaluate the strings as if they are literals and then `sum`

```
df.col1.apply(literal_eval).sum()

[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Thank you. The first method is simplest but how do I use it if I want to concatenate a few first list instead of all the lists in the column? I had already tried out np. concatenate() but I got the same thing as ['[1,2,3...]'].

Comment: @SarwatFatimaM you can do several things.  try `df.col1.iloc[:3].sum()` to combine just the first 3.

Comment: Yes, I have tried this out: `ids = pd.DataFrame(GCM.loc[0:2, 'User IDs'])`
    `ids = uninstall_ids['User IDs'].sum()`  But the problem is its type is str which creates problem further in the program. If I use list() or tolist() then it converts [12,13,14,15] to something like ['['1',',','2',',','1',',','3'...]']. I need this to be a list as i am using counter() from collections to compare to two lists later on in the program. I have also tried out `df.col1.iloc[:3].sum()` but same issue.

Comment: I am not sure how my pandas column converted to type str because I did not do it one my own. I am loading the data from excel sheet though.

Comment: @SarwatFatimaM ahh, I'm pretty sure those are strings and not lists.  I'll update post with a possible solution.  Hopefully it helps.

Comment: Thankyou. I am looking forward to it.

Comment: @SarwatFatimaM I've updated my post further.  If this doesn't solve your problem then the issue is with you not providing sufficient information.  Consider providing a sample csv or code that produces your initial dataframe.  Read [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for further guidance.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to flatten the list this is `pythonic` way to do it:

import pandas as pd

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [[1,2,3], [4,5,6]]})

a = df['A'].tolist()
a = [i for j in a for i in j]
print a
```

Comment: But this results in something like this ['[', '1', '2', ',', ' ', '4', '2', ',', ' ', '4', '9', '2', ',', ' ', '1'.........]'].